# How to run Python Django and Celery using docker-compose?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I've a **Python** application using **Django** and Celery, and I trying to run using **docker** and **docker-compose** because i also using **Redis** and **Dynamodb**

The problem is the following:

I'm not able to execute both services **WSGI** and **Celery**, cause just the first instruction works fine..

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  dynamodb:
    image: dwmkerr/dynamodb
    ports:
      - "3000:8000"
    volumes:
      - dynamodb_data:/data
  jobs:
    build:
      context: nubo-async-cfe-seces
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redisrvi
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
      - CC_DYNAMODB_NAMESPACE=None
      - CC_DYNAMODB_ACCESS_KEY_ID=anything
      - CC_DYNAMODB_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=anything
      - CC_DYNAMODB_HOST=dynamodb
      - CC_DYNAMODB_PORT=8000
      - CC_DYNAMODB_IS_SECURE=False

    command: >
      bash -c "celery worker -A tasks.async_service -Q dynamo-queue -E --loglevel=ERROR &&
               uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http --wsgi-file nubo_async/wsgi.py"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - dynamodb
    volumes:
      - .:/jobs
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
volumes:
  redis_data:
  dynamodb_data:
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: It's more architectural notice but I believe that you need to make separate services for `jobs` and `web` app parts. In `jobs` you run `celery worker` etc, in `web` service - `uwsgi ....` As you don't follow rule "1 process - 1 container".

Btw, what do you see something in `docker-compose logs -f jobs` ?

Comment: @Satevg  logs showing only  Celery process info nothing about Django.

Comment: You can try to use semicolon instead of `&&`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187148 Maybe celery does not return success code, but that's another problem

Comment: @Satevg your first comment gave me the answer here: https://ruddra.com/docker-do-stuff-using-celery-using-redis-as-broker/ is the example of what you mentioned, I need to separate the services. thanks for the tip!

Comment: There's no direct dependency between celery and uwsgi process, so semicolon is ok, you can give a try inside the same container. But it's better to make these services separate for sure.

Comment: This is the first time I need to run a same image in 2 different containers inside the same cluster, at first it seemed strange, but it really is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to `docker-compose` of [*Saleor*](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor) project. I would suggest to let `celery` run its daemon only depend on `redis` as the broker. See the configuration of [*docker-compose.yml*](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file:

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        STATIC_URL: '/static/'
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    env_file: common.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

    celery:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
          args:
            STATIC_URL: '/static/'
        command: celery -A saleor worker --app=saleor.celeryconf:app --loglevel=info
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
          - saleor-backend-tier
        env_file: common.env
        depends_on:
          - redis
```

See also that the connection from both services to `redis` are set separately by the `environtment vatables` as shown on the [*common.env*](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/common.env) file:

```
CACHE_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the docker-compose as suggested by [@Satevg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614426/satevg), run the Django and Celery application by separate containers. Works fine!

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  dynamodb:
    image: dwmkerr/dynamodb
    ports:
      - "3000:8000"
    volumes:
      - dynamodb_data:/data
  jobs:
    build:
      context: nubo-async-cfe-services
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
      - CC_DYNAMODB_NAMESPACE=None
      - CC_DYNAMODB_ACCESS_KEY_ID=anything
      - CC_DYNAMODB_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=anything
      - CC_DYNAMODB_HOST=dynamodb
      - CC_DYNAMODB_PORT=8000
      - CC_DYNAMODB_IS_SECURE=False    
    command: bash -c "uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http --wsgi-file nubo_async/wsgi.py"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - dynamodb
    volumes:
      - .:/jobs
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
  celery:
    build:
      context: nubo-async-cfe-services
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
    - CC_DYNAMODB_NAMESPACE=None
    - CC_DYNAMODB_ACCESS_KEY_ID=anything
    - CC_DYNAMODB_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=anything
    - CC_DYNAMODB_HOST=dynamodb
    - CC_DYNAMODB_PORT=8000
    - CC_DYNAMODB_IS_SECURE=False
    command: celery worker -A tasks.async_service -Q dynamo-queue -E --loglevel=ERROR
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - dynamodb
    volumes:
    - .:/jobs
volumes:
  redis_data:
  dynamodb_data:
```

Comment: Little bit refactored your config (DRY ;)) https://pastebin.com/Mbz72QyD
See `jobs` service definition